# How to find asymptotic order of a function?

Tags: data-structures

I have to arrange several functions like n.logn, log(log(n)) etc in asymptotic order, I have no idea how to do that, Can somebody please help me out?

I know this is not a "do my homework" forum, but I would really appreciate if somebody can help me do this! Thanks.

Comment: is this a rigorous proof-based math class, or a less strict programming-type thing, or...?

Comment: It is a "Algorithms and Data Structures" class for Masters students. It doesn't have any much programming except implementing the sorting algorithms.

Answer (score 1):

The order of a function describes how the requirements of a function scales as the size of the input increases.  So log(log(n)) would scale better (be more efficient) for large n than n.log(n) since log(log(n)) < n.log(n) for all values of n.  In practice, you also have to worry about hidden constants, which could potentially greatly affect the performance of an algorithm (i.e. 9.log(n) = log(n), where the 9 drops out).

A useful table can be found here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Orders_of_common_functions

Comment: So how should I illustrate the steps? Should I just assume 2-3 values for n like 1,2,10 etc and then solve all of them and arrange it?

Comment: What, specifically, does the question ask?

Comment: List the functions below from the lowest asymptotic order to highest asymptotic order.
nlog(n),  log(log(n)),  [log(n)]2,  log(n2).

Comment: The 2 means square over there!

Comment: Then are you required to show work?  Since the problem seems fairly straightforward, it really doesn't seem like it'd require any work unless, as mfrankli was asking, it is a proofs class.

Answer (score 0):

An [interesting reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Table_of_common_time_complexities) for you to start with...

> - constant time - **O(1)** (e.g. Determining if an integer (represented in    binary) is even or odd
> - logarithmic time - **O(log n)** (e.g. Binary search)
> - quadratic time - **O(n2)** (e.g. Bubble sort; Insertion sort)
> - etc...

Answer (score 0):

Take ratios of the functions and calculate the limits of the ratios as n goes to infinity. You can use L'Hopital's rule if it's not immediately obvious from the ratio.

[http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27Hôpital%27s_rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule)

Then you can also do numerical checks to see if your result makes sense.

For the above example, the limit of ( log(log(n)) )/ ( n log(n) ) is zero, so n log(n) grows much faster!